# MYSQL - stored procedure and prepared statements handling quotes

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

From PHP I am using prepared statement ( by binding parameters) and sending data to the below stored procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_my_add_comment(in var_details text, in var_table_name varchar(50))
BEGIN    
    SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',var_table_name,'(details) VALUES("',var_details,'")');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

**My Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `details` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If the text doesn't contain any quotes it is inserting the record , But in case if the text contains quotes it is throwing any error .

Could any one suggest me a resolution for this ?

My assumption was prepared statements should handle this case .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I tested this on MariaDB 10 and it works:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_my_add_comment`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_my_add_comment`(IN `var_details` TEXT, IN `var_table_name` VARCHAR(64))
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN    
    SET @`add_comment` = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', `var_table_name`, ' (`details`) VALUES (', QUOTE(`var_details`), ');');
    PREPARE `stmt_add_comment` FROM @`add_comment`;
    EXECUTE `stmt_add_comment`;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt_add_comment`;
    SET @`add_comment` = NULL;
END;

CALL `test_my_add_comment`('This is a test','test_table');
```

I added a lot of `backticks` because they help you get a better error message if you use a reserved word. I used the correct syntax for prepared statements and I free @add_comment. Also, it is better to use specific names for prepared statements, because if you use the same name in more places you could have problems. And I turned the second param to VARCHAR(64) because it is the real table names maxlength.

Comment: Thank You for your help . This helped me  . Sorry for late response on this one

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in the procedure. Here's how to escape the quotes. I use single quotes here. And I also quote the table/column names.

```
SET @s = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `',var_table_name,'` (`details`) VALUES(\'', QUOTE(var_details), '\')');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . getting this error  Error:4/25/2013 9:28:46 AM 0:00:00.062: Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test_table'')' at line 1
1: call test_my_add_comment('test_table','This is a test')

Comment: Can you copy the exact query you used? SO I can look for "test_table"

Comment: Thanks for your response and here it is call test_my_add_comment('This is a test','test_table')